# Regex - how does one prevent two periods in a row when validating

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I have been struggling on trying how to figure out how to prevent two periods in a row on a validation page.

What I am trying to get is:
..thisisinvalid = invalid
.this.is.valid = valid

After searching around I came up with this
`(?!.*[.]{2})[A-Z][A-Za-z]*`
However this also does not work.

Edit:
I'm new to this + stackoverflow, sorry ahead of time
I'm working on a webpage and currently we are using a form, so the css looks like this currently:

## IDName:invalid{background-color:red;}

## IDName:valid{background-color:green;}

we are using patterns
currently our pattern line is:
"/^(?!.*.{2})[A-Za-z0-9_.+-']"

Ideally we were trying to set it up so it works for email format with everyone before the @  and we have been struggling to prevent multiple periods in a row because they are not accepted by our interface

Answer (score 0):

Try using `RegExp.prototype.test()` with `RegExp` `/\.\./` , which tests input string for two consecutive period characters , returns `true` if pattern matched , `false` if pattern not matched

```
/\.\./.test("..thisisinvalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var isValid = function(str) {
   return !str.match(/\.\./);
}
```

or

```
var isValid = function(str) {
   return !/\.\./.test(str);
}
```

Here you have working example:

```js
(function() {
  var isValid = function(str) {
     return !str.match(/\.\./);
  }
  
  document.getElementById('button').onclick = function(e) {
     var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
     var result = isValid(text) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid';
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
  }
  
})();
```

```html
<input type='text' id='text' /> <span id='result'></span>

<br>
<br>
<button id='button'>Check</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this use case regex is overkill, you can get away with just using `String.indexOf` for instance

```
"mystring".indexOf(".."); // == -1
"my..string".indexOf(".."); // == 2
```

then just compare to `>= 0`

Answer (score 0):

Considering a token by line:

```
/^((\.(?!\.))?[a-z]*)+$/img
```

Comment: does the / +/img matter, we tried a variation of this however our page broke completely

Comment: Yep, matters. The expression is conditioned to one token by line. If you guys need the tokens to be matched in a wide text please send me a sample just to know where tokens begin and end.

Comment: <label class="form_left">Organization Name:<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <input 
   type="text" 
   id="OrganizationName"                   
   class="form_input"             
   name="OrganizationName"                 
   title="Enter the name of the Organization" 
   pattern="[A-Z][A-Za-z]*" 
   placeholder="e.g. BestBuy"         
   size="32"                       
   maxlength="32"                  
   tabindex="0"                   
   value=""                        
   required                         
  />

There is some sample code from our organization unit page.